# Select element form a dropdown list using Selenium webdriver Chrome

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to choose a value from a dropdown list using vba Selenium. In Chrome, using ChroPath I've obtained the relative Xpath "*//option[contains(text(),'Fiyat De')]*" and also the absolute Xpath but later when I put them in my code, I receive **NoSuchElement** error in vba. I've been also tried to check the Xpath using the XPath Helper extension but it appears as "Null". I've also tried clicking first on the dropdown list and then clicking my desired value (2), but again, same error.

Below the vba code options I've tried:

```
'Using XPath
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[@id='fileView_ctl01_cmbTur']").Click 'To click on the dropdown list
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//option[contains(text(),'Fiyat De')]").Click 'To click on the desider option
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='1f219fbb-3e12-406f-bc6a-27f8935c1cb9']").AsSelect.SelectByValue ("2")
'Using also Css    
    bot.FindElementByCss("body.claro:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(28) td:nth-child(4) div.css-dropdownlist select:nth-child(1) > option:nth-child(2)").Click 
'Using ExecuteScript
    bot.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('fileView_ctl01_cmbTur').value = '2';"
```

Below part of the HTML code from which I want to select option value="2" style="">Fiyat Değişikliği:

```html
<td width="203" height="20" valign="top" colspan="3" rowspan="2"><div class="css-dropdownlist" style="width:201px;"><select name="fileView$ctl01$cmbTur" id="fileView_ctl01_cmbTur" style="width:223px;text-decoration:none;height:23px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:9pt;font-family:Tahoma;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;TEXT-ALIGN:left;background-position:183px 4px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Miktar Değişikliği</option>
    <option value="2">Fiyat Değişikliği</option>

</select></div></td>
```

I have tried multiple combinations, using Xpath, css, but so far nothing has worked. I am new using this tool so maybe this is a simple error. Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: Instead of hand-crafted HTML, update the question with the text based actual HTML.

Comment: I have just copied and pasted part of the actual HTML (the one referring to the dropdown) using the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this selector?

select[name$='$ctl01$cmbTur] > option[value='2']

Comment: I am new using selenium, so could you please guide me on whether you mean using it like: bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[name$='$ctl01$cmbTur] > option[value='2']").click ?  Is that a Xpath? Thanks

Comment: try:

bot.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name$='$ctl01$cmbTur] > option[value='2']"));

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. Still same error.

Comment: I first pasted the line you suggested on my code but Excel showed me a sytaxis error. Then I modified by:   bot.FindElementByCss ("select[name$='$ctl01$cmbTur] > option[value='2']")         And the new error is: Run time error 32: Invalid selectorError  Invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified (session info ... Driver info... )

Comment: I see thanks for updating the code. Can you access the selector using the browser? If you you can use wait for the selector first before accessing the element.